# Call a function over elements of a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I am completely new to python and Pandas of course. I am trying to run a function "get url" which is function to get the complete/ extended url from small Url . I have a data frame in python consists all the short URLs. Now I am trying to do with following ways. One is to use "for" loop which loops and apply function  on all the elements and will create a another series of extended URL but I am not able to , dont know why , I tried to write it like

```
for i in df2:
     expanded(i) = get_real(df2[[i]])
print(expanded)df2.[i,'expanded']
next()
```

and i want also pass a function which will resume next on error but not sure how to do it.

again second solution i tried was passing a whole array to applymap fucntion

```
df4 = df3.applymap(get_real)
```

but this also doesnt work for me .

Thanks for all the help !

Comment: Your code doesn't look like valid python.

Comment: can you dput what your function is doing? Adding the same suffix to each url or particular suffix proper to each base url?

Comment: It'd be better if you could post more code

Comment: `for i in df2
     expanded(i) = get_real(df2[[i]])` doesn't work because the iterable returned is the column not each element, so unless your code understands how to operate on a pandas Series then your code won't work

Comment: Hi.. this is my defined function.. def myfunction(url):                                           exturl=urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(url)).geturl()
    return exturl   and I am applying it on my list df3['new']=df3['first_link'].apply(myfunction)... but because or errors its not working .. that why looking for for loop

Answer (score 1):

If the short urls are a column in the pandas dataFrame, you can use the `apply` function (though I am not sure if they would resume on error, most probably not).

Syntax -

```
 df['<newcolumn>'] = df['<columnname>'].apply(<functionname>)
```

I am hoping all the short urls would be different rows in a single column.

If you want to use `for` loop , then you can do something like -

```
for idx in df.index:
    try:
        df['<newcolumn>'][idx] = <functionname>(df['<columnname>'][idx])
    except <TheError you want to catch or if you do not know, leave empty>:
        <Do logic for handling the error>
```

Comment: Hi.. this is my defined function.. def myfunction(url):                                           exturl=urllib2.urlopen(HeadRequest(url)).geturl()
    return exturl   and I am applying it on my list df3['new']=df3['first_link'].apply(myfunction)... but because or errors its not working .. that why looking for for loop

Comment: Updated the answer with a solution using `for` loop. please check.

Comment: Hi Anand - Thanks for help. but it is working same as apply function. as soon as it faces a error it pass completely. error is like HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found....

Comment: ANd i am using the formula for idx in df5.index:
    try:
        df5['new'][idx] = myfunction(df5['first_link'][idx])
    except: #<TheError you want to catch or if you do not know, leave empty>:
        #<Do logic for handling the error>
         pass

Comment: do a pass inside the except, if you do not want to do anything

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you are having is treating the dataframe just like a dictionary that has keys and values.

I think all you need to do is use

```
new_df = df2['expanded']
```

But you should show us what the df2 looks like